# Does the Passthrough Authentication via AD Connect support RDP with Azure virtual machines?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

When the user sign-in method for AD Connect is password hash sync, using on-premise domain credentials can be used for RDP sessions into Azure virtual machines.  When the user sign-in method of AD Connect is changed to pass-through authentication, these same on-premise credentials cannot be used for RDP sessions to Azure virtual machines.  Is the type of security that RDP uses not compatible with the pass-through authentication option in AD Connect?

What's interesting is that enabling the optional password hash sync feature when configuring pass-through authentication allows RDP to work.  My understanding is that enabling the optional password hash sync feature is a failover technique that would need to be manually enabled if the on-premise domain was not reachable.

It seems, however, that both methods of authentication are being used depending on what is being accessed.  We did a test by disabling an account from on-premise domain when running under pass-through authentication.  This change was immediately reflected in the Azure portal because we were NOT able to login to the portal.  However, when trying to RDP to a VM inside this same Azure subscription, I was able to use the same credentials even though the account was disabled.

Is this by design or is our configuration messed up?  It would seem to be a big oversight not to allow pass-through authentication to work with core applications such as RDP.

Comment: The VM is windows or Linux? And you could grab the network package to check the log.

Comment: The VM is a Windows 2016 Data Center server.  The traffic is hitting the box because the security log in the VM event log indicates the user failed to login.  This only happens when pass through authentication is enabled with no password hash sync option.

Comment: It really comes down to whether or not pass-through authentication can be used for these types of scenarios.  If you look at the limitations guide, I'm not sure if it falls under "legacy protocol applications" or not.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-pta-current-limitations